# How to override <base> tag without removing the tag itself?

Tags: html

I'm trying to add some hash links (in the format of a content table, to be able to facilitate webpage navigation) to this site in which a `<base>` tag is used.

Now obviously due to the base tag, every other relative tag will be relative to the base tag href. In order for me to create this internal content table with the links pointing to different parts of the specific page, I need to get the default URL (before base tag is in effect) so the internal links can work properly.

Is there a way to do get around the base tag and accomplish this?

Comment: "internal links pointing to different parts of the specific page"... Are you talking about hash links, like: `href="#tab-2"`? Can you give any example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The effect of the `base` tag is global to the document, and the only way to override the effect of `<base href="...">` is to use absolute URLs.

You can use `window.location` in JavaScript to get the URL of the page itself, in case the document was retrieved via HTTP. And you could use it to construct absolute URLs.

The `base` tag is normally not needed these days. It is better to use server-side technologies that let you construct addresses from one or more base addresses. So quite possibly the best approach is to get rid of the tag.

Comment: I use ecommerce software that unfortunately *relies* on the `<base>` tag, so it is still out there. Possibly little known fact: `../relative` links do work with the base tag if your base is a subdirectory.

Comment: Links that start with ../ naturally work with a base address that contains a segment in the path part. You are then not overriding the `base` tag, just moving around under its influence.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, Yes we can generate links using server tags. But that's not a reason against using `base href`. Indeed `base href` is useful at many situations.

Comment: @Pacerier, the `<base href=...>` tag affects *all* URL-valued attributes in the document. It is easy to forget this or fail to notice the tag when editing a document and adding a relative URL, for use in a link, an image reference, or other element that has a URL-valued attribute.

Answer (score 5):

You could 'fix' this using some javascript and jQuery -

```
// get all the internal anchors inside #article 
$('#article a').each(
        function() {
            // get the href attribute
            href = $(this).attr('href');
            // does it have a href?
            if (href) {
                // does it have an internal anchor?
                if (href.match(/#/i)) {
                    // append window.location and write back to the href Attribute
                    new_href = window.location + href;
                    $(this).attr('href', new_href);
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is better to use `var` when defining variables, otherwise they will be defined in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

As a slight alternative, to have local urls and keep the base href you could try this.

```js
$('a.local').each(
    function () {
  // get the href attribute
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  // does it have a href?
  if (href) {
   var lastSlash = window.location.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
   var new_href = window.location.toString().substr(0, lastSlash + 1) + href;
   $(this).attr('href', new_href);
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<base href="http://www.google.com">
<a class="local" href="mylocalpage.html">local page</a>
<a href="pageOnRemoteServer.html">remote page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to include a relative stylesheet, ignoring the `href` in the `base` tag. I found that if I put the stylesheet `link` before the `base` tag, the `href` does not get affected.

I based it on this info:

> If either of the following attributes are specified, this element must come before other elements with attribute values of URLs, such as ’s href attribute.

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

I realize that this most likely will require you to put your `a` tags in the document `head`, and then somehow style them to appear at the correct locations. So this trick might not be very usable.

NOTE: The documentation says that the base tag "must" come before elements that use an URL, so what I've done might not be legal according to the specification.

Comment: I had to use the base tag in a document I fetched by php curl and display it with other relative urls in my document. My <script> and <link> tags with relative urls come before the base tag and they work without getting affected by the base.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `/` before the link should do the work. Let's say you have `<base href="/assets/images/" />`. If you use `<img src="logo.png" />`, than it loads `/assets/images/logo.png`. Otherwise, if you use `<img src="/logo.png" />`, it loads `/logo.png` from the root directory.

Comment: *Adding a /* is half correct... Assuming you just skipped the protocol and leave the double `//`.

Comment: This solution only works in very specific instances. If you know the URL of the image relative to the root, it will work. But often you want to use a URL relative to the current page, without necessarily knowing the current page's path at development-time.