# AnimateMotion does not work if <base> is in <head>

Tags: html, svg

I am using `<svg>` with `<animateMotion>` in my web app. All works fine until the web has tag `<base>` in its `<head>`.

This code does not work. But if you remove `<base>` tag from `<head>` part, animation works just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/k4v1fnhb/2/

Does exist any way to solve this problem?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1121708, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449027 // The Mozilla guys argue that the SVG spec is rather ambiguous on this. (I can only repeat my mantra here: Don’t use the `base` element, it creates more problems than it solves. I personally have never seen any need to use it so far.)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I can not change the html code of page where I use this app, if so, removing base tag would be the easiest way of course.

Comment: So your app is not a stand-alone app, but gets embedded into other sites? Then your only option to avoid this might be to separate your app from the “parent” page, by putting your content into an iframe, so that it is independent of such “settings” of the parent.

Comment: Using window.location according this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16194653/2548459 - fixed the problem.