# Internal href of <a tag now refreshes the page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, anchor, internal

I've got several anchor tags pointing to internal links mainly to scroll to some section titles or to get to the top from a bottom link of the site since some pages can get very long.

All tags like `<a href="#whatever">Whatever</a>` just scrolled the page to the `<a name="whatever"></a>` tag as intended until yesterday, but now when clicked they force a page refresh pointing to the root page with just hash, like this `localhost/#whatever` instead of this `localhost/path/to/current/page/#whatever`.

1) Is there even the possibility to alter something in the Apache server, browser settings (not touched tough), HTML/JavaScript/CSS code of a page or whatever to force page refreshes when clicking on internal links?

2) If I change the anchor to `<a href="path/to/current/page/#whatever>` it works, but it's just because a page refresh triggers and then the page is scrolled like normal when interpreting the hash fragment. Also, this way I loose any GET parameters (I can't predict them) which I really need since it's a database website

3) If I alter or remove the `<base href="/" />` tag nothing happens, still the internal links worked before with that tag in place

4) I recently updated the .htaccess file and that could potentially be the cause but still routing has no problems and I can't see why any `RewriteRule` could possibly affect internal links. Also, trying to revert it to previous version didn't help

5) Same behavior applies to both Firefox and Chrome, latest versions

6) I tried to create a test page in the same environment (same .htaccess, same HTML base template) with just a very long `<ul>` list containing list elements with integers in sequence until 500, then a `<a href="#20">To 20</a>` at the bottom of the page and it just worked all good... What can force a internal link to redirect?! Please help

Comment: Can you show us an actual page exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: I finally solved it! Check here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108836/make-anchor-links-refer-to-the-current-page-when-using-base) and here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303241/how-to-override-base-tag-without-removing-the-tag-itself). The problem was with the `<base href="/" />` tag. I had to use jQuery, here `$("a.local").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location.hash = "";
  document.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
 });`

Comment: Thanks @RadLexus, I did not know

Comment: No problem at all! Now everyone can see by the "accepted" mark that this question has an answer that worked for someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it! Check here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108836/make-anchor-links-refer-to-the-current-page-when-using-base) and here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303241/how-to-override-base-tag-without-removing-the-tag-itself). The problem was with the `<base href="/" />` tag in the `<head>` section. I solved with a mixture of jQuery and pure JavaScript (jQuery is used only for select anchors and get attribute), here

```
$("a.local").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.location.hash = "";
    document.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Please note that I need to set the hash to an empty string before actually setting it to the href of the anchor since `document.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");` alone would not trigger automatic scrolling on multiple clicks on the internal anchor (I tried it)